# Cannot get jQuery ajax to respond to any status response other than 200

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I'm trying to get jQuery ajax to tell me the status response codes from urls, however it only seems to respond when it's a 200.

What I've done is set up a localhost PHP form and am passing in urls from this site: http://savanttools.com/test-http-status-codes which returns status codes, to jQuery's ajax function.

Below is the code which receives the url and I've commented the responses I get. Bascially I can't seem to get anything meaningful unless the reponse is 200, whereas I want the script to recognise any status response code. Any help appreciated!

```
function UrlStatus(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,     
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        statusCode: {
            404: function() { console.log("status code 404"); }, // not triggered regardless of status
            200: function() { console.log("status 200"); }, // only triggered when status is 200
            502: function() { console.log("status 502"); } // not triggered regardless of status
        },
        jsonpCallback: function() {
            console.log("jsonp callback"); // always triggered regardless of status
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log("complete"); // only triggered when status is 200
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("error"); // only triggered when status is 200
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("success"); // not triggered regardless of status
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("fail"); // only triggered when status is 200
    }).always(function() {
        console.log("always"); // only triggered when status is 200
    }).done(function() {
        console.log("done"); // not triggered regardless of status
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no way to get status codes with JSONP

Comment: Thanks - I've tried removing the jsonp type but then I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin error - is there any way to test urls without this error?

Comment: a) the server could send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. b) if it's just to test your code with different status codes point to your own server that sends them (`node -e "require('http').createServer(function(req, res) { res.writeHead({{ statuscode }}, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); res.end('wat'); }).listen(8080)"`)

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily change your request from jsonp to something else and expect it to work. The only solution I can think of is to make the request server side.